# Include other files and Folders in custom Kickstart ISO using mkisofs

Tags: linux, centos

I'm unable to figure out how to include some directories and files that I've added to my custom CentOS 6.4 32 bit kickstart install.  Is there a way to add these custom directories/files to my output iso (mycustom.iso) using mkisofs or kickstart?

**command used to generate CentOS image:**

```
#mkisofs -o mycustom.iso -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot \
   -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T isolinux/
```

Comment: IIRC, you should put your directories under the rootfs you've created, where you want to see your directories.

Comment: @rakib....can you add you response as a answer so I can accept it as you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the additional directories under the rootfs you've created, where you want to see your directories. mkfsiso takes the last arg as rootfs, where additional directories can be added also.